# On the relation between traces and characteristic polynomials

Tags: matrices, terminology, trace, invariance, characteristic-polynomial

I know that the trace of an $n \times n$ matrix is invariant and results from adding the diagonal entries. I also know that the characteristic polynomial of that very same matrix is also invariant, and somehow that invariance seems more primitive than that of the trace.

1. What is the relation between those two invariances?
2. Does the trace derive from a primordial invariant represented by the underlying polynomial?
3. How exactly can that relation be characterized, both logically and numerically? I heard sometime that the trace merely multiplies the polynomial by some factor ($\times (n-1)$) or something along those lines, I really do not recall.

Could you please elaborate on that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The trace is, up to sign, a coefficient of the characteristic polynomial. The coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, up to sign, are the traces of the action of the matrix on the exterior powers of the underlying vector space.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you define the characteristic polynomial $P(\lambda)$ of the matrix $A$ as $P(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id}_n)$, then $\operatorname{tr}A$ is the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$ in $P(\lambda)$ times $(-1)^{n-1}$. Therefore, the invariance of $P(\lambda)$ implies the invariance of $\operatorname{tr}A$.

Comment: Does that mean that the primary invariance, so to speak, is that of the polynomial, and that of the trace is derived from it?

Comment: I wouldn't say that, since the invariance of the trace can be proved without even knowing what the characteristic polynomial is or what a determinant is. It follows from the fact that $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$.

Comment: so those two invariances are orthogonal?? It does not seem to me. I mean, the invariance of the trace may be proved (logically) without knowing the characteristic polynomial, but, as far as I understand it, it cannot be numerically determined without the characteristic being known? Correct? If that is the case, it seems like there is one primary and one secondary invariance there, so to speak.

Comment: I cannot answer your question, since I don't understand it. What do you by “characteristic”?

Comment: i mean the characteristic polynomial

Comment: Then I don't understand what you mean when you say that the invariance of the trace “cannot be numerically determined without the characteristic [polynomial] being known”.

Comment: Let us go step by step, to avoid confusion.  The trace is a number, correct? The addition of the numbers in the diagonal? Correct?

Comment: In oher words, if the reace can be directly calculated by summation of the numbers in the diagonal, and we knwo that thet trace of AB is the same as that of BA, then, why do we need the characteristic polynominal in relation to the trace at all?

Comment: We **don't** need it. I just observed that we *can* extract the trace from the characteristic polynomial and to deduce from that and from the invariance of the characteristic polynomial that the trace is invariant.

Comment: Ok...but could be somehow be argued that the invariance of the characteristic polynominal is logically primary and that that of the trace is derived? That is, that they have a different logical or epistemological status? The trace is a number, the polynomial is a function. So one might say the number comes from assigning arguments to the function.

Comment: I don't see how.